# How to suppress PowerShell errors while script is running get-wmiobject. -EA doesn't work

Tags: powershell, error-handling, wmi

Here is my script.

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration 
-computername (get-content .\computers.txt) -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" |
select PSComputerName,DNSServerSearchOrder
```

My Get-Content is going to have a huge list of computers, ones that don't exist anymore in my network, and ones that do. So while generating this list, I will be getting "RPC Server not available" in red error text. I don't want this to display at all. I've tried doing `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or `Ignore` with no change in behavior.

I've also tried this:

```
try {
get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration 
-computername (get-content .\computers.txt) -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" |
select PSComputerName,DNSServerSearchOrder
}
catch {
}
```

This has given me no luck either. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by doing

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration 
-computername (get-content .\computers.txt) 2>$null -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" |
select PSComputerName,DNSServerSearchOrder
```

And I also was doing -ErrorAction after the Select, you need to do this before the select in the wmi pipeline. Hopefully this helps someone like me in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You don't show us how you are using `-ErrorAction silentlyContinue`. If placed properly that would have suppressed your errors. I'm guessing you put it on the end of your command as supposed to associating it to `Get-WMIObject`.

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -computername (get-content .\computers.txt) -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
select PSComputerName,DNSServerSearchOrder
```

Your try catch block would have also worked but I think it would have stopped processing on the first error thereby skipping the other good computers.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think about throwing that -EA in my syntax on here for some reason. Thanks for the comments.